# union of two dataframes' index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, union

I am not sure if it is the right expression, but searching merge or change index didn't get me anywhere. Basically I have two dataframes:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame(1, index=[1,2,3], columns = [1,2,3])
df_B = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[1,2,4], columns = [1,2,5])
```

I want to transform df_A and df_B such that both share the same index and columns, which are the unions of the two. The missing values will be filled with NaN:

```
df_A_new:
          1    2    3    5
index
1         1    1    1   NaN
2         1    1    1   NaN
3         1    1    1   NaN
4        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

df_B_new:
          1    2    3    5
index
1         0    0   NaN   0
2         0    0   NaN   0
3        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4         0    0   NaN   0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) and [`.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

```
rows = df_A.index.union(df_B.index)
cols = df_A.columns.union(df_B.columns)

df_A_new = df_A.reindex(index=rows, columns=cols)
df_B_new = df_B.reindex(index=rows, columns=cols)
```

`df_A_new` looks like

```
     1    2    3   5
1  1.0  1.0  1.0 NaN
2  1.0  1.0  1.0 NaN
3  1.0  1.0  1.0 NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
```

`df_B_new` looks like:

```
     1    2   3    5
1  0.0  0.0 NaN  0.0
2  0.0  0.0 NaN  0.0
3  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
4  0.0  0.0 NaN  0.0
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what i am looking for! apparently i cant accept an answer within 10 mins.... so i'll click your answer by then